# Как поменять стиль у того элемента, на который навел мышь

Tags: c#, blazor

Я написал простенькую таблицу пифагора, где мне нужно взаимодействовать с каждой ячейкой таблицы. То есть, я навожу на ячейку и она перекрашивается в другой цвет. Сделать я это хочу только с использование Blazor и C# (без JavaScript). Может будут у кого какие предложения? Пробовал использовать @ref - ничего не получилось

```
@{
    <table>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                <tr style="width: 25px; height: 25px; background-color: wheat; text-align: center; font-family:Arial">
                    @for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
                    {
                        if (i == j)
                        {
                            Item item = new Item(false);
                            Items.Add(item);
                            <td @ref="item.er" @onmouseout="() => item.isOver = false" @onmouseover="() => item.isOver = true" 
                                style="@(item.isOver ? "background-color: green" : "background-color: red")" >@(i * j)</td>
                            @*<td style="width: 50px; height: 50px; font-weight:bold; border: 4px solid black; color: #ddff34; background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #5baf5a, #85fd85)">@(i * j)</td>*@
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <td style="border: 4px solid black; width: 50px; height: 50px">@(i * j)</td>
                        }
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: [ASP.NET Core Blazor event handling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Используйте одно из событий мыши (onmouseover, onmousemove)

Comment: а зачем это делать с помощью C# и Blazor если можно просто использовать CSS. Просто соответствующий класс *класс* для ячейки, для него создайте *класс* :hover и присваивайте *класс* своим ячейкам. И при наведении они будут стилизоваться классом *класс*:hover.
http://htmlbook.ru/css/hover